# How to stop "Site Members" group modifying Quick Launch or Top Nav?

Tags: permissions, groups, quick-launch, top-link-bar

With the standard groups and permission levels how do you stop "Site Members" modifying the Quick Launch or Top link bar?

Comment: Interesting. Can't see any site permission mask which corresponds to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Customize-navigation-links-on-the-Quick-Launch-8e663db5-9839-4eb9-9ce9-4f0c264adb82?CorrelationId=00b83360-f42f-4c16-8ac8-902d2e995ce8&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) references that users must have Full Control or Design permission to be able to modify the quick launch (for 2007, but afaik, this has been unchanged throughout the versions). It doesn't explicitly say which of the permission masks enables it. Has your Site Members group had it's permission level modified? Based on this, they should not be able to.

Looking over the permissions for design and contribute, Add and Customize Pages could be the culprit. Does your Member group have this mask included in their permission level?

Edit 1:
And the corresponding [top link bar article](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-top-link-bar-43f854a5-adc3-4a6f-a87e-4f1506a7c0b0?CorrelationId=7746ddad-d242-4821-ae9d-d9af286fc92b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) says the same thing, Full Control or Design permissions are needed to edit that.

Edit 2: Here are articles for 2010 [top link bar](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-top-link-bar-for-site-navigation-1b614211-2882-4507-a791-8716090c9905?CorrelationId=8939be52-f8f9-4abf-b602-0ccc2a253576&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc273611127)  and [quick launch](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Quick-Launch-for-site-navigation-d3288963-4a91-4470-9192-610952daecdf?CorrelationId=f11c39da-548e-4160-aa57-f1615712183b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and they say:

> To manage navigation for a site you must have at least the permissions
>   obtained by being added to the default Designers SharePoint group for
>   the site.

Comment: Member group and all permission levels are 'OOTB' (running this on a frequently snapshot reset test system). Additionally I seem to remember (though can't find reference now) that the way the quicklaunch is implemented under the hood is different 2010 onwards.

Comment: I don't recall hearing an underlying change to those, but if you do find links please share. I'll see if I can locate anything too.

Comment: Updated with 2010 links

Comment: By default, members in SP 2013 have Edit permissions and "Add and customize pages" is not set. So is the case with contribute permissions.

Comment: Strangely this seems to be different in 2010 to 2013. Members group and/or edit permissions still allow access to Top Link / Quick Launch

Comment: This didn't appear to work on 2013 in my testing (but did on 2007/2010). Tried 2 different 'fresh' environments so pretty sure no modifications to standard permission levels. Asked a new question specific to SP2013 here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131326/how-to-stop-site-members-group-modifying-quick-launch-or-top-nav-in-sharepoint