# How to stop “Site Members” group modifying Quick Launch or Top Nav in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, permissions, quick-launch, top-link-bar

With the standard groups and permission levels how do you stop "Site Members" modifying the Quick Launch or Top link bar in **SharePoint 2013**

([This related post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131199/how-to-stop-site-members-group-modifying-quick-launch-or-top-nav) answers the question for 2007 and 2010, but doesn't appear to work on SharePoint 2013)